# Bitstamp FIX Environment

Tags: fix-protocol

I am developing a trading app for bitstamp's FIX environment.  When I submit an order (msgtype=D), I get an execution report (msgtype=8) that states the order was rejected due to a invalid nonce.  However, bitstamp's FIX documentation does not specify that a nonce parameter is needed for FIX orders.  Does anyone know how I may resolve this error?

Comment: This sounds like a problem that is specific to Bitstamp.  Plain old FIX doesn't do nonces.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Mystery solved.  I was using the same authentication keys to perform both REST calls and submit FIX messages at the same time.  Bitstamp does not allow this.  You must have separate keys for each type of process.  Luckily, bitstamp support got back to me after some time.  They just need to specify this in their specs, since other exchanges are more lenient and allow this.

Comment: Off-topic, but since the documentation doesn't seem to contain all the answers, can you verify whether their FIX api host is fix.bistamp.net, or something else. Their support is painfully slow despite claiming to have onboarded me.

Comment: `fix.bitstamp.net` port `8905` is their fix host, and it has worked for me